# Sci-fi book for teens, probably from the early 90s about orb-people from a future of human evolution, inhabiting modern college kids

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

The characters are orb-people from a future of human evolution, and part of a class is them inhabiting modern college kids. It's basically them reacting to normal college drama with no experience with sensory perceptions or emotional/chemical responses. There was annoying romance drama, but I still think about the concept. There's 2 boys & 2 girls & I think I was also annoyed by some of that 80s/90s 'gender psychology' stuff.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/series/106172-extreme-zone?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember the cover art or any of the character names?

Comment: The cover looked more 80s than 90s. They all had very typical american names. I don't remember any violence or action, or even mystery.

Comment: @Alxb - Was it the book series I've mentioned in my comment above?

Comment: Sorry, no. That series had mystery & violence. The one i remember was a stand-alone (as far as i knew) n character drama as a plot. It might have been older than i remember because it was from the library.